# Point-to-point network between three servers

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, ip

I have a three servers, each of which has two network ports. I want to connect these servers using point-to-point connections without using a switch.

Here is a diagram of what the physical connections look like:

```
   +---------+
   |  Node A |
   |    |eth0}-----+
   |         |     | +---------+
   |    |eth1}-+   | |  Node C |
   +---------+ |   +-{eth1|    |
               |     |         |
               |   +-{eth0|    |
               |   | +---------+
   +---------+ |   |
   |  Node B | |   |
   |    |eth0}-+   |
   |         |     |
   |    |eth1}-----+
   +---------+
```

I want the servers to be able to talk to each other. What I mean by this is:

- The servers should be part of the same IP network, e.g. 10.10.10.0/24.
- Each server should have an IP address, e.g. 10.10.10.1 for node A, 10.10.10.2 for node B and 10.10.10.3 for node C.
- The IP packets should take different routes depending on their destination. For example, when on node A, packages with destination 10.10.10.2 (node B) should be routed through `eth1` and packages with destination 10.10.10.3 (node C) should be routed through `eth0`.
- (Edit: The following is not a strict requirement, but would be nice to have.) Broadcasts should be routed through both physical ports. Packets to all other addresses can be discarded.

Is it possible to create a network configuration that achieves this?

One idea I had was that I could create a virtual ethernet interface on each of the nodes and then add some routing rules. But I'm not completely sure if this is the right way. And I'm also not sure how to achieve the correct routing of broadcasts.

Another idea was that I could create a network bridge (consisting of both ports) on each of the servers and configure spanning-tree to make sure that only one bridge is active.

But I guess that a bridge is not necessary, because all nodes can be reached directly.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome!

**Edit:**
Some background information: (This information is not necessary to solve the problem, but I want to describe the context of the problem and make a point why this is question is relevant for this forum.)

What I'm trying to achieve here is to set up a Ceph cluster consisting of three nodes. Each node is equipped with an Intel E810-CQDA2 NIC and two 100GBASE-SR4 transceivers. I use  OM4 fibres for the interconnection. This is a business setup, with hardware costs of more than 30k (without the NVMe SSDs).

The purpose of all this is to create a test system with Ceph, to see if Ceph could be a relevant technology we could use in the future. At this point in time I don't want to invest money into 100G switches, because of the high costs of such an investment (from what I've seen so far, it's not possible to buy good 100G switches for less then 10k, and you basically need two of them to avoid a single point of failure). If we roll out Ceph into production at some point in the future, we already have the appropriate data centers with the switch infrastructure in place. But as of now, this is only a test environment, and I want to keep it strictly separated from production.

Comment: Why you complicate so much the things? Add switch between all the servers and you are in the business.

Comment: @Romeo Ninov: Well, I think point-to-point connections shouldn't be considered as too complicated. If 100 Gbit switches were cheaper, I would buy two of them and then connect the three nodes using LACP bonding to the switches. But they are very expensive (and an overkill if you only want to connect three nodes).

Comment: Business environment != unlimited budget

Comment: Why the requirement to keep them on the same subnet? (using different subnets for each pair seems to offer more scope for exploiting the configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Create `bond` interfaces on each host which enslave both physical NICs, and use bonding mode 3 `broadcast`. Each server will transmit all the thaffic to both counterparts. Connect them into a "ring" (or "triangle"). Then simply assign addresses from the single network block to all servers.

```
ip link add name bond0 type bond mode broadcast
ip link set eth0 master bond0
ip link set eth1 master bond0
ip link set eth0 up
ip link set eth1 up
ip link set bond0 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev bond0
```

Repeat on all servers, using different IP addresses from the same subnet on each. Voila!

Example: we used this technique around 10 years ago to connect three Proxmox VE nodes to run CEPH network over 10 gigabit between them. 10gpbs switches were very expensive, but we had 2-port 10gbps cards in our disposal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it within the next few days. My use-case is the same as yours: I also want to use it for Ceph on Proxmox VE, but with 100 Gbit ports. And 100 Gbit switches are really expensive.

Comment: This solution acually was borrowed from Proxmox forum or wiki of that time. I don't know if it's still available in original location. Also I must warn you: 100 gbps links are really 4x25 gbps. It might be possible you only get 25 gbps for each single data stream.

Comment: This is bullshit. You’re confusing NIC teaming with a bandwidth split @ the physical level. In a nutshell: With 100 GbE you can use splitter cable to have 4x25GbE or 2x50GbE, but you’ll have ONE 100 GbE uplink if you want pumping ALL the traffic!

Comment: https://www.optcore.net/understanding-100g-ethernet/

Comment: 4x25G lanes
Next, we will talk about SR4 / LR4. It is 4 lanes of 25 G each. More precisely because of the encoding overhead, it will be 4 x 25.78125 GHz. It also stripes packets to 64b / 66b blocks before sending all connections, including BIP8 error detection (Note: error detection is not correct). However there is a habit here, there are actually two different standards for 4 x 25 G connection. IEEE 802.3 ba and IEEE 802.3 bm.

Comment: Key point: packets (Ethernet frames) will travel using ALL the lanes. This IS different from trunk or team or whatever.